# Notice связаный с константами

Tags: php

Задание написать калькулятор с выводом всех ошибок и их исправлением. Для идентификации операции, в `<option value = "MATH_MN">*</option>,` и при проверке в        `case MATH_PLUS:` используются строки `MATH_MN`, `MATH_SUMM`, и т.д. Изначально все работает, но есть 4 нотиса:
`Notice: Use of undefined constant MATH_DILL - assumed 'MATH_DILL' in C:\OpenServer\domains\urok4.com\index.php on line 21` и т.д.
Если обьявить эти строки константами, как `define ("MATH_DILL",1);`, код перестает работать.

Comment: в case `MATH_MN` нужно заключать в строки

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно было просто при проверке в `case MATH_DILL:` взять строку в кавычки, как `case "MATH_DILL":`.